# $f(x) = x^3 - x$ then $f(n)$ is multiple of 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

If $f(x) = x^3 - x$ then $f(n)$ is multiple of 3 for all integer $n$.

First I tried $$f(n) = n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)\qquad\forall n\ .$$

When $x$ is an integer then  at least one factor on the right is even, and exactly one factor on the right is divisible by $3$. It follows that for any $n\in{\mathbb Z}$ the right hand side is divisible by $6$, and so is the left hand side. That is to say: $n^3=n$ mod $6$ for all integers $n$.

Is that correct? or there are another simple solution for this? Thanx.

Comment: Your logic is perfect but you really went further than you need to. To say $$f(n) = n(n+1)(n-1)$$ is enough. As you point out, for every $n$ one of $n$, $n+1$, and $n-1$ must be a multiple of 3. Therefore $f(n)$ will be a multiple of 3 as to get f(n) one of the factors is a multiple of 3.

Comment: Regarding "*or there are another simple solution for this?*", I'm not sure if you'd call this simple, but you can prove it by mathematical induction. Since $f$ is an odd function, and multiplication by $-1$ preserves both divisibility by $3$ and non-divisibility by $3,$ it suffices to prove this for $n=0,$ $1,$ $2,\;\ldots$ For the inductive step, note that $(n+1)^3 - (n+1) \; = \; n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 - n - 1,$ which equals $(n^3 - n) + 3(n^2 + n),$ which is divisible by $3$ (the first parentheses part by induction hypothesis).

Comment: The simplest solution is citing [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_Little_Theorem).

Comment: Well, clearly the elliptic curve described by $y^2=x^3-x$ has complex multiplication and is isogenous to the modular curve $X_0(32)$.  At $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, we can see $X_0(32)$ has rank 0 and it's torsion group is $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 4 \mathbb{Z}$, so $Y_0(32)(\mathbb{Q}(i))$ has four points.  So back on the original curve, this tells us that reduction to $\mathbb{F}_3$ is... you should take it from here if it's homework.

Comment: See also: [Prove by induction that $3\mid n^3 - n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/562699) and [Proof that $3\mid n^3 − 4n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1439002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $3\mid n$ then the result obviously follows. Otherwise, by FL(ittle)T, $n^3 \equiv n \pmod 3$ so we are done.

Answer (score 4):

After you get $f(n)=n(n+1)(n-1)$, meaning $f(n)$ has factors $n$, $n+1$, $n-1$. Now you want to show $3$ divides one of them.

If $3\mid n$ then you get what you want.

If $3\nmid n$, then $n\equiv 1$ or $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Meaning $3\mid n-1$ or $3\mid n+1$