# Proof that $3\mid n^3 − 4n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $n^3 − 4n$ is divisible by $3$ for every positive integer $n$.

I am not sure how to start this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: We recently talked about mods i.e. 5=2(mod3). since 3I (5-2)

Comment: Factor this as a polynomial in $n$.  Also have a look at [the introduction to using MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: $n^3-4n=n^3-n-3n=(n-1)n(n+1)+3n$ and $(n-1)n(n+1)$ is a product of $3$ consecutive integers (or notice $3\mid n^3-n$ by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)).

Comment: This seems related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562699/prove-by-induction-that-3-mid-n3-n

Comment: I meant $(n-1)n(n+1)-3n$ in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one can start off by factoring $n^3 - 4n$:

$n^3 - 4n = n(n^2 - 4)$
$= n(n + 2)(n - 2); \tag{1}$

next we note that every $n \in \Bbb Z$ is of one of the three forms

$n = 3q, \tag{2}$

$n = 3q + 1, \tag{3}$

or

$n = 3q + 2; \tag{4}$

this follows from the basic properties of [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) applied to $n$ with $3$ as the divisor; the only possible remainders $r$ be $0$, $1$, and $2$, since such integers $r$ must satisfy $0 \le r \le 2$.  In case (2), clearly $3 \mid n$; in case (3), we have

$n + 2 = 3q + 1 + 2$
$= 3q + 3 = 3(q + 1), \tag{5}$

showing that $3 \mid n + 2$; finally, case (4) yields

$n - 2$
$= 3q + 2 - 2 = 3q, \tag{6}$

whence $3 \mid n - 2$.  For evey possible $n$, $3$ divides one of the factors of $n^3 - 4n$ occurring in (1); thus we have $3 \mid n^3 - 4n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$.  ***QED.***

Answer (score 1):

$n^3-n-3n = n(n^2-1)-3n = n(n-1)(n+1)-3n$. As, $3|3n$ and $3|(n-1)$ or $3|n$ or $3|(n+1) \implies 3|n^3-4n$

Comment: (+1) this is the first thing that came to my mind. Nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
n^3-4n
&=6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}-3\binom{n}{1}\\
&=3\left[2\binom{n}{3}+2\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{1}\right]
\end{align}
$$